# How To Integrate VAST Video Ads use smaato sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

How To Integrate VAST Video Ads use smaato sdk..It is only supporting MP4 and 3GP video files ? i have create demo with video ad but getting error..
    SOMAInterstitialAdView* adview = [[SOMAInterstitialVideoAdView alloc]init];
    self.adView = adview;
    self.adView.delegate = self;
    [self.adView load];